# How to convert selenium script to splash? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Faced the problem of converting the script from selenium to splash.

Please help me how to correctly click "Next" and pass the result in a loop. I read about LUA scripts, but not understood how to do it.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(https://gplplugins.club/changelog/)
        x = 1
        for i in range(20):
            time.sleep(10)
            selenium_response = scrapy.Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            items = selenium_response.xpath("//tr[@role='row']")
            for item in items:
                link = item.xpath(".//td/a[@class='single-product-link']/@href").get()
                name = item.xpath(".//td/a[@class='single-product-link']/text()").get()
                date = item.xpath(".//td[@class='col-date sorting_1']/text()").get()
                version = None
 
                if link and name != None:
                    yield {
                        'link': link,
                        'name': name,
                        'date': date,
                        'x': x
                    }
 
            x += 1
            next_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "//div[@id='text-13']/div[@class='textwidget' and 1]/ul[@class='menu' and 1]/li[1]/a[1]")
            actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
            actions.move_to_element(next_element ).perform()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wc-product-table-below wc-product-table-controls']/div[@class='dataTables_paginate paging_simple' and 1]/a[@class='paginate_button next' and 2]").click()
 
        self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you please update the question to explain what the issue is?

Comment: I checked the source of the page you mentioned. I don't see the elements you're looking for. I checked this URL: https://gplplugins.club/changelog

Comment: @Mike67 Button "NEXT"...xpath("//div[@class='wc-product-table-below wc-product-table-controls']/div[@class='dataTables_paginate paging_simple']/a[@class='paginate_button next']")